# Using an array without the last element is simple in Python, `array[:-1]`. How would index splicing of this sort work in C?

Tags: python, arrays, c

In Python, if I have a list A, if I wanted to use that list without including the last element in the list, I could just use `array[:-1]`. How would I get the equivalent for C?

Comment: There's nothing equivalent in C. C doesn't have any built-in array manipulation methods.

Comment: If you use a function that takes an array and length as parameters, you can simply call it with `length-1` as the second argument.

Comment: (ec) If you have an array `a[]` and a variable `n` that keeps track of the number of elements in it, and if you have function calls like `f(a, n)` that operate on arrays, you can obviously call `f(a, n-1)`.  But I concede that's kind of a lot of if's.

Comment: Note that under those same assumptions, it's just about as easy to skip an element at the *front* of the array: `f(a+1, n-1)`.

Comment: Note an important difference: A Python slice is a new list, but if you use this technique in C you're passing the same array. It makes a difference if the function modifies the array.

Comment: @Barmar, that actually worked for my use case. I think it could deserve its own answer, though I have accepted the one already here as it would do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Negative indexing is a feature that is only available in python, and there is no such equivalent of it in C. However, to access the last element of an array you could use this code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int array[8] = {1, 2, 3 ,4, 5 , 6, 7, 8};
  lastIndex = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])-1;
}
```