# Assign stack adress of an array with last element removed?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory, stack

In the language C, I want to copy `array A` to `array B`, with the additional constraint, that in `B`, the last element of `A` should be removed.

Could I, dynamically, just set the pointer of `B` to `A`, but somehow make the array only extend to the memory adress `&A - sizeof(A[0])`? How?

Thank you!

Comment: Please define 'removed'.  Do you mean 'not copied'?  You cannot copy an array by assigning a pointer to the source array - you have to copy all the data you need to.

Comment: Is this some homework question? [Very similar question asked earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75962525/9952196).

Comment: Is there no way to have two pointers point to the same adress? Would be useful, for storing a reference, but with the given constraint of having one less element.

Comment: And no, I can confirm it is holidays and definitely no homework question. Maybe the universe wants us to solve pointers.

Comment: Also note that, without a defined, terminating 'sentinel' value or a 'length' variable tied to the array, it is often not possible to determine the length of an array, so there can be no 'last element' to remove.

Comment: You can have two pointers point to the same address, but that is not usually considered 'copying' of any data at that address.

Comment: That is true. Would be cool, to have pointers with stack length.

Comment: You can define a type that has a length and, with  a bit of pointer arithmetic, allow that type to be referenced by a single pointer to the first element of the data.  That is common with string types in other languages, but C does not have that natively:(

Comment: C uses '\0' as the sentinel which is size of 1.  With one byte string length variable the maximum string size is 255.  If you need large you need a bigger length variable, size_t, for instance on my system is 8 bytes.  Small strings are common so you don't want to always use a large length.  This means you probably end up with a more complication union of structs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use memcpy() to copy data between arrays:

```
size_t B_len = sizeof A - sizeof *A;
memcpy(B, A, B_len);
```

This leaves the B at whatever size you had to begin with.

If `A` is a pointer to a (dynamically allocated) array then you need the size or length of the array to be able figure how many bytes to copy.

You would need `malloc()` or `realloc()` to dynamically allocate an array of the right size for `B`.  For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   int A[] = {0, 1, 2};
   size_t B_len = sizeof A - sizeof *A;
   int *B = malloc(B_len);
   // TODO: handle error of B == NULL here
   memcpy(B, A, B_len);
   free(B);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so far, very helpful. As I understand, this would copy the values of the array to another location in memory. If I'd only want a "shallow copy", or a reference, copied, then I'd probably just copy the pointer, and decrease an additional length variable.

Comment: You can create a pointer to first element of the array `int *B = &A[0];` and it would up to calling code to make use of `B_len` to use all but the last elements.  C doesn't have a concept of references.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I'm using right now!